# VBA excel how to check if offset of a cell, refers to a cell inside the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to check how many neighbors of a cell, are empty. 
How do I do this when I don't know if my cell has 8 neighbors or less? 
Here's my code. It only works when my cell is not on the first or last row or column of a worksheet.

```
Sub neighbors()
Dim count%, i%, j%
count = 0
For i = -1 To 1
    For j = -1 To 1
        If VBA.IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(i, j)) Then count = count + 1
    Next j
Next i
' If activecell is empty - don't count it
If VBA.IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then count = count - 1
MsgBox count
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by 'neighbors' but could the .Count of the .CurrentRegion property (possibly limited by Intersect) work?

Comment: Neighbors are the 8 cells that surround a cell unless the cell is in the first or last row or column in which case there are fewer neighbors. The CurrentRegion  property will not help because the neighboring cells may be empty or some may be empty and some full so you cannot predict what the currentregion will be.

Comment: Please note that I made a small adjustment to my coded answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of the calculated boundaries and use that to define your block of 'neighbour' cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub neighbors()
    Dim n As Long, bounds As Variant

    With ActiveCell
        bounds = Array(Application.Max(1, .Row - 1), _
                       Application.Max(1, .Column - 1), _
                       Application.Min(.Parent.Rows.count, .Row + 1), _
                       Application.Min(.Parent.Columns.count, .Column + 1))
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Parent
        With .Range(.Cells(bounds(0), bounds(1)), .Cells(bounds(2), bounds(3)))
            Debug.Print .Address(0, 0)
            n = Application.CountBlank(.Cells) + CBool(IsEmpty(ActiveCell))
        End With
    End With

    MsgBox n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, you need to check `ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column` to see if they are the first ones.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub neighbors()

Dim count As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim firstRow As Long, FirstCol As Long

count = 0
If ActiveCell.Row < 2 Then '<-- first row 
    firstRow = 0
Else
    firstRow = -1
End If
If ActiveCell.Column < 2 Then '<-- first column ("A")
    FirstCol = 0
Else
    FirstCol = -1
End If

For i = firstRow To 1
    For j = FirstCol To 1
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(i, j)) Then count = count + 1
    Next j
Next i

' If activecell is empty - don't count it
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then count = count - 1
MsgBox count

End Sub
```

Comment: In this solution one would need to also check for last row or column.

Comment: @hil  why ? Are you going to use ActiveCell at row >65 thousand something something ?

Comment: Theoretically, yes. Is there a constant I can use to know the number of the last row and last column? I don't mean "end".

Comment: In that case you'll need to check if ActiveCell.Row = 1,048,576 , you think you'll get there ? The same for column